# What is "Push Funding" in PayPal's Express Checkout API?

Tags: paypal

The PayPal Express Checkout API's [FundingSourceDetailsType](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_SOAP/#fundingsourcedetailstype) has a field named `AllowPushFunding`.

> (Optional) Indicates whether the merchant can accept push funding. It
>   is one of the following values:
>
> 0 – Merchant cannot accept push funding.
>
> 1 – Merchant can accept push funding.

What exactly is "push funding" in the context of Express Checkout?

Comment: Good question I never see that one before ... !!